# Editing an .htaccess file to do multiple things

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have an .htaccess file containing the following:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest ajax
<FilesMatch "uploadImage\.php|connect\.php|connect2\.php|deleteFile\.php">
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from env=ajax
</FilesMatch>
```

I would like to add the following additions:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 40M
php_value post_max_size 40M
php_value max_input_time 300
php_value max_execution_time 300
```

How do I go about putting both of those in one .htaccess file (i.e. what's the correct syntax?)

When I simply add the lines at the bottom I get 'Internal Server Error'

Comment: Simply put it on a new line at the bottom?

Comment: @Darren Please review my edits

Comment: Can you check your error logs and see what's there?

Comment: @Darren `[Tue May 24 01:12:23 2016] [alert] [client 89.238.166.146] /home/thebeis/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://thebeis.co.uk/shiurim.php`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes different servers won't allow you to specify a php_flag change in the htaccess file.

The best way to debug is to introduce a single line

try adding this line in your htaccess file

```
php_value error_reporting 6135
```

If this causes an internal server error then your system doesn't allow you to set the values through the htaccess file. You will have to use ini_set

```
ini_set('error_reporting', 6135);
```

If this doesn't work either you might have to talk to your host.

Also try clearing out everything in your htaccess file and put a single php_flag line in there to see if it works. Then you know there are no conflicts between what you've already got in there and what you want to add

Comment: Every time I try to load a php ini file, my ability to use session storage disappears!

Comment: What do you mean load a php.ini file? Are you overwriting your php.ini file with a different one?

Comment: No.. I never had one to begin with. I just put a default for my PHP in my public_html folder and now my session storage doesn't work. The session save path is correct.

Comment: That seems like a different issue to this question. Do you want to post a separate question for that?

Answer (score 0):

If your server is running in CGI mode, you'll have to modify the php.ini file or make apache run it as a module.

https://support.tigertech.net/php-value